# SSL Connect Error on Magento Connect after upgrading to 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento-connect, ssl, ce-1.9.2.4, magento-connect-manager, downloader

I'm having problems with Magento Connect again. I'm using Magento 1.9.2.4.

Last year, when using Magento 1.9.2.2, I previously had the `"Unknown cipher in list: TLSv1"` error when using Magento Connect to install extensions.
 I used this solution to solve it:

```
/* $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1'); */
$this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1);
```

However, I have since upgraded to 1.9.2.4 (directly from 1.9.2.2), and now I get the error message "SSL connect error" when trying to install any extensions via Magento Connect.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

$this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');
To this:
$this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1);

in downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php

Comment: This change is already in place. (I said in the original post that I have already made this change, in order to stop the "Unknown cipher in list: TLSv1" error.)

Answer (score 1):

[It's not safe to use Magento connect for installing extension , click this link for more information.](https://www.integer-net.com/why-modules-shouldnt-be-installed-via-magento-connect-manager/)

in the worst case, if you want immediate solution , Alternatively you can install the extension through FTP (like FileZilla). You can paste the extension key [in this unofficial link](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php) and you can download the extension files. Let me know if you find any problems in this.

**Note** : As this is unofficial 3rd party site, there is no guarantee about security. but i tested many extensions, i did't faced any security problems....

Comment: I'm now using this technique, just to get the extensions installed - but I'd rather use the 'official' method rather than a workaround if at all possible.

Comment: @PhilStewart thats better , best thing is installing extension in demo site and check quality of code and make sure extension will not breaks anything and install in live site

Comment: The downside is that you can't see a list of all the extensions that have been installed. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @PhilStewart means you are telling you want to see all extensions of the site under `magento connect`, you can check that by `system > configuration > Advanced > Disable modules output`......

Comment: Oh that's fantastic - I've never seen that before!

Comment: @PhilStewart also you can check all modules installed under app/etc/modules section.

Comment: Just had a thought: how do I find out which version of the various extensions has been installed?

Comment: @PhilStewart if you go to app/code/community/company_name/module_name/etc/config.xml , you can see version name in tags as

<version>3.5.4</version> , you can these links for more information 

https://www.artio.net/faqs/components-and-extensions/version/where-to-find-version-of-installed-extension-in-magento-system

http://www.magentron.com/blog/2011/07/20/how-to-display-your-extension-version-in-magento-admin